# How to I configure Thinktecture IdentityServer to use Unity IOC Container

Tags: unity-container, server, identity, thinktecture

Currently my web app uses unity IoC. I am trying to use Unity to register all my dependencies that the Identityserver needs for my custom userservice. 
I am also hosting the identityserver in the same web application.

Answer (score 1):

I was able with ServiceLocator

In Startup.cs

```
app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
{
  var factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
            clients: Clients.Get(),
            scopes: StandardScopes.All);


 factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUserService>());
```

And In my Unity config

```
container.RegisterType<IUserService, LocalRegistrationUserService>();
```

And In My custom User service

```
public class LocalRegistrationUserService : IUserService
{

    IUser userBusiness;

    public LocalRegistrationUserService(IUser userBusiness)
    {
        this.userBusiness = userBusiness;
    }
```